# Windows Server 2012 caught in reboot loop with error 0xc000021A

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

After installing a few recent updates[1], a Windows 20012 R2 server demanded a reboot. Instead of coming back normally it got caught in a reboot loop with error 0xc000021a. The following was attempted but with no success:

- repair mode
- last known good
- safe mode

Most finds on the internet seem to match XP/2000/2003 instead and provided no help. 
What can be done (short of a complete reinstall)?

---

[1] I'm not 100% in reconstructing this, but according to what my WSUS reports as "downloaded" for that box, I suppose the updates were KB3084905, KB3094486, KB3095649, KB3095701, KB3096433 - just in case that's helpful.

Comment: You could...... restore it from backup.

Comment: You need to boot up to an install disk so you can access a command prompt and view your logs to determine what's wrong.  Or, as suggested, restoring from backups should be quicker and easier.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Sounds reasonable. Since the last reboot was quite long ago, it is at least possible that it was not the recent action (updates) that broke something ...

Answer (score -1):

You can uninstall updates from command line with this code:

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:{update ID}
```